# Swift position and constraints programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uilabel, constraints

I have the following view:

[image]

I have to place a `UIButton` or a `UILabel` below **Account balance** depending if this movement is rejected or not (just check a variable).

I've created programmatically the button & label depending on that, but I don't know how to add it to that specific place and add constraints.

```
func checkRejected () {
    if !movement.rejected {
        let xposition = amountLabel.frame.origin.x
        let yposition = balanceLabel.frame.origin.y + 300
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: xposition, y: yposition, width: 100, height: 50))
        button.setTitle("Reject", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(rejectAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(button)
    }
    else {
        let xposition = amountLabel.frame.origin.x
        let yposition = balanceLabel.frame.origin.y + 300
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: xposition, y: yposition, width: 100, height: 50))
        label.text = "Rejected"
        label.textColor = UIColor.red
        self.view.addSubview(label)
    }
}
```

How I could do that?

Comment: Also think of whether you need it 300 or 30 as it may exceed some iphones screen height

Comment: This can certainly be done with code, but if everything else is in a storyboard, add the button and constraints in the storyboard too, and then just set it's `hidden` property to `YES` when you don't want to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
self.view.addSubview(button)
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([ 
    button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.balanceLabel.bottomAnchor,constant:30),
    button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
])
```

Same for the label

**Note:** Since the button and the label have an intrinsic content size , then we don't have to set width && height

Comment: So, what are we doing is: First, place the button below the balance label with a distance of 30, and then center to the middle on X axis, no?

Comment: And what about button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints? Sorry, but it's the first time I set constraints programmatically

Comment: you should always set it to false for programmatically creating constraints  , read https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622572-translatesautoresizingmaskintoco